# Reverse Cuthill Mckee in Python

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix

How can i use the permutation array returned by Scipy [RCM](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.1/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csgraph.reverse_cuthill_mckee.html), to reorder the original sparse matrix and reduce the bandwidth?

```
B = mmread('G22.mtx')
graph = csr_matrix(B)
aux2 = reverse_cuthill_mckee(graph,symmetric_mode=True)
```

Where 'graph' is a undirected graph(symmetric matrix).

Comment: Probably with matrix multiplication - or even two.  scipy sparse uses matrix multiplication to perform row or column indexxing.

Answer (score 3):

I found the answer, if anyone needs it in the future:

```
B = mmread('G22.mtx')
graph = csr_matrix(B)
aux2 = reverse_cuthill_mckee(graph,symmetric_mode=True)


for i in range(len(aux2)):
    graph[:,i] = graph[aux2,i]
for i in range(len(aux2)):
    graph[i,:] = graph[i,aux2]
```